# Azure AD SSO with SAML edit Attributes & Claims via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application set up in Azure AD with Single Sign-On with SAML.  I need to be able to edit the Attributes & Claims programmatically via the Microsoft Graph API.  I've scoured the API documentation but cannot seem to find a way to access Attributes & Claims with it.

Not sure if it matters, but specifically, I'm trying to edit the conditions of a specific claim.

Answer (score 1):

For now, editing attributes & claims through graph API is only possible through custom claim policy. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api#step-3-configure-claims-mapping) article on how to edit claims in SAML app through graph API

Please note that once you configure claims mapping policy via Graph API, you will not be allowed to edit the claims in Azure portal any longer, which is by design.

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  That explains so much.  Thus far everything was done manually so no claims mapping policies were ever created.

Comment: is it possible to create/edit claims conditions this way?  I've seen the documentation for creating custom claims mappings, but can't find anything on conditions

Comment: The attributes and claims in the portal assigned to application -- don't they create claims mapping policy for the servicePrincipal? I manually assigned SAML attributes for the app and when I try calling the claimsMappingPolicies endpoint from Graph it gives an empty response.